# Pass FileUpload.PostedFile as parameter (server side method)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, pagemethods

I'm quite new to the asp.net world, so I would appreciate any help or different solutions.

Does anybody know of a way to pass the PostedFile (HttpPostedFile) of a FileUpload via javascript/jquery to a server side method?

Client-side?
//how do I pass the FileUpload.PostedFile?

codebehind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void SaveMyFile(HttpPostedFile myFile)
{
// code to save file here
}
```

NOTE: I don't want to make use of plugins or any other thirdparty controls.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do but have a look at the answer on this SO post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689461/fileupload-postedfile-to-pagemethods-sever-side-method

Comment: @PaulZahra you have posted this SO link..

Comment: @Paul, your link is pointing at my post. anyhow, basically what I want to do is to create my own file upload control. and save the file without causing postback, hence making use of pagemethods

Comment: Gah sorry... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241545/how-to-correctly-use-the-asp-net-fileupload-control

Answer (score 0):

This script can be used to post a file,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('filecontrol').files[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "url");
    xhr.send(fd);
      }
</script>
<input type="file" id="filecontrol" />
<input type="button" onclick="send()" value="Upload File" />
```

and in server side you can get the posted files by using

```
HttpPostedFile hpf = Request.Files[0];
```

Comment: Hi Wings of Fire, thank you for the reply, much appreciated. I am getting the error 'FormData' is undefined. any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: seems like it might be related to the fact that I am using IE 9. From a quick search on google found that FormData only works on IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my mistaken comment earlier... anyway I believe this may well be what you want... [ajax file upload using jquery file upload plugin](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/asp-net-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery-file-upload-plugin/)... the [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) plugin is pretty sexy