# getting the content of uploaded file from fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

If I use a **file upload control** in an ASP page and the user had uploaded PDF file, how I can get the content of this file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly use the ASP.NET FileUpload control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241545/how-to-correctly-use-the-asp-net-fileupload-control)

Answer (score 0):

You could used the PostedFile property to access the content of the file. Using PostedFile you can get the content length, contenttype etc. Also you can directly save the file as

```
sFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadCtrl.value)
sFilePath = Path.Combine([your new path] , sFileName)
FileUploadCtrl.PostedFile.SaveAs(sFilePath)
```

Comment: okay , i know that PostedFile property to access the content of the file but it get the content in form of bytes and i want the content of file in form of text

Comment: You can not extract text from pdf file. You will need an iFilter for this. See the sample in this code project link.. It will give you an idea of what i am saying.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C